# ASP MVC 3 OutputCache avoid cacheing current request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, outputcache

I started using OutputCache for my website. 
The problem that I encounter is that when a user update an item I need to reset the cache for that item.

I did that using:

```
var urlToRemove = Url.Action("Details", "Dress", new {id = model.Id});
Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(urlToRemove);
```

In Edit action I also set to TempData the update success message and I display it on the next request. The problem is that the message remains in the cached response.

Do you know how can I avoid caching in an action. Something like:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "id")]
public ViewResult Details(int id)
{  
  if(NotificationHelper.HasNotifications)
    Response.DoNotCache();
    .....
```

I cannot use the same trick ... because the page is added to the cache after its rendered. So I cannot exclude an action from cache in its body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is sometimes referred as "Donut Hole Caching" because you want to cache everything except some bit of dynamic content in the middle.

Here is are a couple resources you might want to look at:

- http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3
- https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth/wiki/Server-side-caching

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an easy way to do what you are asking. However, my experience with messages and OutputCache is don't put them in the response. I ended up making sure there were no messages that are ever displayed on a cached page. If I absolutely had to have a message on a cached page I would set up an ajax call that would grab the messages once the response reached the client.

Comment: Erv's suggestion of donut holing the message is also a good idea if you are able to integrate a third party caching library.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
class CustomOutputCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode >= 400)
        {
            this.Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None;
            this.Duration = -1;
        }

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

}
```